# Class.forName() takes too long to return a Class in JUnit

Tags: java, reflection, junit, classloader

```
@Test
public void test() {
  ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  ImmutableSet<ClassInfo> classInfoSet = ClassPath.from(classLoader)
            .getTopLevelClassesRecursive("com.example");
  for (ClassInfo classInfo : classInfoSet) {
    Class<?> clazz = classInfo.load();
    doSomething();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to process 20,00 classes to check if annotation usage is correct. The problem is classInfo.load() takes too much time for specific classes (approx. 20% of all classes).

I replaced this method by the following code for debug and confirmed that Class.forName() takes more than a few minutes for specific classes.

```
String className = classInfo.getName();
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(className);
```

I've run this program many times and it always slows down at the same classes and speeds up at other classes. I tried running the test for smaller package with 20 classes, but the speed didn't improve. Those slow classes have normal amount of codes and couldn't find a problem.

I thought it's a memory issue and added the setting below to VM arguments, but nothing changed.

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=2048M
-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit
```

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please clarify how exactly are you launching the `test()` method? Is there any parallel execution implication, or you're processing 20K classes in a single thread?

Comment: Also, as `class.forName` performs not only class loading but also static initialization, could you please clarify how are static initialization blocks in problematic classes, if any, look like?

Comment: I just selected the test method and clicked Run As > JUnit Test on Eclipse. I've run the test for smaller package with 20 classes, but the speed didn't improve.

Comment: Most of the slow classes don't have static initialization blocks.

Comment: I suspect the slow classes are at the head of long dependency chains involving classes you haven't loaded yet, so they all have to be loaded first. A topological sort of the classes so that you do these last would fix it, but what 'too much time' means when executing a unit test is another mystery. You could also try `Class.forName()` with `false` for the initialization argument.

Comment: I tried "Class.forName(className, false, classLoader);" but couldn't improve the performance.

Comment: So put the slowest one at the end and see.

Comment: > I suspect the slow classes are at the head of long dependency chains   

This could be right. Classes in submodules with few dependencies are faster than other classes.